# Word header logo grayed out, color changed

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

Spent hours trying to find an answer to how to fix this. When I insert a jpeg logo into the header in Word 365, looks fine until I close the header, which is then a great deal lighter. Please help! Tried saving as a Template, no luck.

Comment: When you will print the document it will be with the original color. By default word will gray out your header and footer just to delimit those areas.

Comment: As Alex suggests, Word dims/blurs the header and foots when you're not actively editing them, so that you know you're not actively editing them, and to visually separate the header/footer from the main body.